# How to Get 2 different data colums from same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this table:

| CODE | SUBCODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 5130 |
| 1 | 100 | 1000 |
| 1 | 983 | -123 |
| 2 | 100 | 598123 |
| 2 | 713 | -7123 |
| 2 | 813 | -78123 |
| 3 | 110 | 5123 |
| 3 | 130 | -8976 |
| 4 | 150 | 951 |
| 4 | 123 | -6891 |
| 5 | 160 | 513 |
| 5 | 512 | -213 |

How can I get list of all positive data columns on the one side and other side with all negative data?

| SUBCODE | VALUE | SUBCODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 598123 | 813 | -78123 |
| 120 | 5130 | 130 | -8976 |
| 110 | 5123 | 713 | -7123 |
| 100 | 1000 | 123 | -6891 |
| 150 | 951 | 512 | -213 |
| 160 | 513 | 983 | -123 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why the previous version of this question was closed, because it was quite clear with sample data and desired results.

With great pain in MS Access -- but it is possible. You need to enumerate the values and then combine them. I think this will work:

```
select max(subcode), max(data), max(subcode_neg), max(data_neg)
from (select subcode, data, null as subcode_neg, null as data_neg
             (select count(*) from t as t2 where t2.subcode <= t.subcode and t2.data > 0
             ) as seqnum
      from t
      where data > 0
      union all
      select null, null, subcode, data,
             (select count(*) from t as t2 where t2.subcode <= t.subcode and t2.data < 0
             ) as seqnum
      from t
      where data < 0
     ) as tt
group by seqnum;
```